# Eclipse changes existing syntax of BPMN2

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jbpm, bpmn

While editing existing BPMN2 file , eclipse change the code which make it unusable.

```
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
  xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" 
  xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" 
  xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" 
  id="Definitions_1" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.jboss.org/drools">
```

to

```
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
   xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" 
   xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" 
   xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" 
   xmlns:drools="http://www.jboss.org/drools" 
   xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/drools" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd 
      http://www.jboss.org/drools drools.xsd 
      http://www.bpsim.org/schemas/1.0 bpsim.xsd" 
   id="Definitions_1" 
   targetNamespace="http://www.jboss.org/drools">
```

and

```
<bpmn2:process id="com.arpit.hello" name="Hello">
```

to

```
<bpmn2:process id="com.arpit.hello" 
   drools:version="1" 
   drools:packageName="defaultPackage" 
   drools:adHoc="false" 
   name="Hello" 
   isExecutable="true">
```

Can any one help me out?

Comment: As long as the namespaced elements (`bpmn2`, `drools`) are compliant with their declared `xsd` schema then it's all ok. `xml` in general allows adding elements and attributes from additional namespaces without loss of information. Any serious `xml` processor can handle it just fine. What's exactly the problem you observe that "_make it unusable_"? (and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: While deploying bpmn it's showing error even after making minor changes like changing some comments
Error is 
An error occurred while reading rule flow xml
message not found

Comment: In order to help we'll need more precise **steps to reproduce**, stack trace from the log file (detailed error message), exact version numbers of the software you're talking about, ...basically a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: After making few changes
i am getting this error
24/03/2015 08:44:29,148 - ERROR [http-bio-8090-exec-6] (ServiceTaskHandler.java:148) - Error when executing work item
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jbpm.process.workitem.bpmn2.ServiceTaskHandler.getWSClient(ServiceTaskHandler.java:164)
 at org.jbpm.process.workitem.bpmn2.ServiceTaskHandler.executeWorkItem(ServiceTaskHandler.java:94)

Comment: Which version of https://www.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/downloads.php do you use? Which version of https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/releases do you use?

Comment: today i switched to jboss developer studio version 7.1.1 GA
BPMN2 modeler 1.0.2.201402102317
jbpm drools guvnor 6.1.0 final

Comment: I have **no idea** of what's actually going on or what might be wrong. Just in case that upgrading your toolset to the latest versions of everything (jBoss Developer Studio 8.1.0.CR1, BPMN2 Modeler ?, Drools jBPM 6.2.0.Final) does not help and official support forums remain silent, you can always build the toolset from source code and put a breakpoint at https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6.1.0.Final/jbpm-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/bpmn2/ServiceTaskHandler.java#L95 and inspect what's wrong in the debugger. I don't use the tools actively so I can't assist you more

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse modeler is currently not trying to preserve formating etc.  It should produce semantically equivant output however.